# Jenkins autobuild goes into a loop when github commit triggers the build

Tags: maven, github, jenkins

I created a webhook in jenkins and connected it to github webhook & services.

I came upon the following issue When the build is completed, the pom.xml is updated with the version and tag . This triggers build job again and its goes into a loop until, I manually stop it .

I have set the build trigger to "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub"

I would like to find out how to stop the build trigger when the pom.xml is updated only as part of the build?

Answer (score 1):

In the `source code management` job configuration section add `Additional Behaviors` and select `Polling ignores commits from certain users` and provide the user name your Jenkins job uses to checkin pom.xml.  You can also use `Polling ignores commits in certain paths` and provide path to pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not committing the version update to the master branch but create a separate tag every time. Something like this:

```
    v1   v2   v3
   /    /    /
--A----B----C (master)
```

I got this approach from [Real-World Strategies for Continuous Delivery with Maven and Jenkins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McTZtyb9M38) video ([corresponding slides](http://www.slideshare.net/wakaleo/continuous-deliverywithmaven)) - it contains other tips on setting up build pipelines with Maven as well.