# Jenkins deploy hook on push / merge, adapting pom.xml going cyclic

Tags: maven, github, jenkins-workflow

In Jenkins, we want to implement a hook on push (merge) to the Git master (GitHub). The goal of this hook is updating the pom.xml.

The problem that we envision is that we would create cyclic process. Updating a pom.xml is a new push (merge), which triggers the hook, which updates the pom.xml etc.

Is there a solution out there that solves this issue?

Comment: Two ways. In Jenkins polling the Git repo or in Git Repo create a Hook to trigger jenkins...but not in Jenkins a hook...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (do not commit to master but to a separate tag) is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707075/jenkins-autobuild-goes-into-a-loop-when-github-commit-triggers-the-build?rq=1).